# What size images should I use for PowerPoint Templates?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I am trying to create some PowerPoint templates for work and need to know what size images to use for the templates so they will look good on the screen. I tried making one with images that are 1024 x 768 pixels and when I view it on a large screen it looks awful.

I have searched and can't find any real clear guidelines for this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure that you also adjust the resolution of your computer to best work with the projector or whatever device you are using to display your powerpoint.

Comment: I also advise you use as many vector based graphics as possible for the template. This isn't quite straight-forward (you must use `.WMF` or `.EMF`), but not so bad once you get the hang of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1280px wide by 720px tall is generally a good size, especially if it will be displayed on an HDTV.